# Missing 't' in class name

Tags: php, symfony

i have no idea what happend, but when im trying to use a command line (e.g cache:clear or assetic:dump) i have error

```
 Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Reques' not found in H:\www\s\skeleton\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1568
```

I see that there is a missing "t" in class name, but why ?

Comment: Just checking the obvious: please paste line 1568 of file `H:\www\s\skeleton\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php`

Comment: Aren't those service containers generated on the fly? Sounds like a bug in your version of Symfony if so.

Comment: This file is in cache folder so i think its generated. Error line: `protected function getRequestService()
    {
        return $this->services['request'] = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Reques();
    }`

Comment: So the code generator seems to have typo'ed :)

Comment: I made a typo in one of my config files. But stack its not perfect :-)

Comment: so you solved your own problem?

Answer (score 0):

Go to that file on your computer, find line 1568, fix the typo, save, run it again. Problem solved.

Typos can and do happen to everyone.

Comment: This file is generated by app. I saw the typo but why its there. Maybe i made somewhere else it, but im sure its not a solution.

Comment: This is just a temporary solution. The minute @Pawel decides to clear the cache, the fix is gone.

Comment: That is not even a temporary solution, because this file is generated foreach request in den env.

Comment: Honestly how did this answer get +3?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have a look in H:\www\s\skeleton\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1568.

Looking at the code at http://code.google.com/p/symfony-2-portfolio-site/source/browse/trunk/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php?r=3 the actual issue might be towards the bottom of the code. Search for "HttpFoundation\Reques" and see if you can find the typo. I can't see it in that version, so I'm guessing it might be fixed in the latest version of Symfony too. You should probably upgrade if you're not on the latest version.

Comment: I've upgraded to 2.0.8 and now i have other error: `Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\DoctrineCommand' not found`